# setting up a remote access between two NATted hosts for remote assistance

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, nat

I need to reach remote sparse machines (ARM Linux Appliances) for maintenance and support.

All these machines are Customer owned and plugged into their own private LANs (where I have no privilege), normally behind a light firewall NATting the LAN to the Internet.

Interaction should be started by Customer (from the Arm Linux Appliance) requesting assistance. Customers (with few exceptions) are not really technically minded, so I can not ask them any setup, just "press that button" when They call me.

I do Have an Internet-exposed server I can use as rely, but my main development machine is behind another NATting router/firewall.

All I need is basic console access (Appliances have no KVM) via ssh or equivalent.

I tried several available solutions (n2n, tinc, pwnat), but I must be missing something essential because all solutions install with no problem, seem to connect to their net (ifconfig shows traffic), but then they do not appear to work (I cannot ping Appliance).

I also noticed the above software is quite old, sometimes obsoleted. What is the current advised "best practice"?

I am aware of LogMeIn (and I will evaluate it), but I would like, if at all possible, to avoid incurring in costly royalties.

Comment: Do they have access to the devices themselves?  Enough to login via ssh for example?

Comment: @Paul: I'm not sure I fully understand Your question. Customers have physical access to their device(s) and can reach them via LAN (browser config pages, something similar to Modem/Router setup pages) but, for the large majority, do not know something like a Command Line Interface exists at all (leave alone using ssh: no way :( ). In theory they could ssh into the machine. I am looking for some way to start (via web interface or physical button) an ssh session where I can control the device from remote (i.e.: from outside local natted domain)